# tmux flow control

Tags: ssh, tmux, flow-control

I'm ssh'ing into a machine running Ubuntu 12.04, and using tmux 1.6, on an ADSL link (8Mbps/1Mbps down/up).

When there's lots of fast terminal output, the link gets saturated and completely unresponsive, and I can't switch tmux windows or anything, and have to kill ssh.

Is there some tmux setting to prevent this? I've seen some patches but it's not clear what they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*tmux* 1.7 and later include a kind of rate limiting. It might help if the output you are dealing with is normal “scrolly” output (lots of normal lines, not (e.g.) a huge base64 encoded block).

Two options control this rate limiting: `c0-change-trigger`, and `c0-change-interval`. Basically, if *tmux* sees more than `c0-change-trigger` of certain C0 control characters (e.g. backspace, linefeed, carriage return) in 1 millisecond, then it will deferring further updates to the pane for `c0-change-interval` milliseconds. The defaults are 250 such C0 characters in 1 millisecond will stop pane drawing for 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Values 10 for trigger and 100 for interval works pretty fine for me: ``setw -g c0-change-trigger 10``, ``setw -g c0-change-interval 100``. They cope even with "huge base64 encoded block".